# What is exactly meant by "set of values" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

A friend of mine asked me to sum up a few numbers.

Instead of using a calculator, I decided to write a SQL statement.
The statement I wrote was:

```
select sum(100,300,200);
```

Then, I got an error.
I jumped to [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions-and-modifiers.html), where it says:

> Aggregate functions operate on sets of values.

If **[100,300,200]** isn't a `set of values`, then what is?

Comment: 'If [100,300,200] isn't a set of values, then what is?' -is a list/array

Comment: mysql has no lists or arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means sets of values *from multiple rows*.

```
mysql> select * from mytable;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|  100 |
|  200 |
|  300 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select sum(num) from mytable;
+----------+
| sum(num) |
+----------+
|      600 |
+----------+
```

If you want to sum up three scalars in one expression, just use `+`.

```
mysql> select 100+300+200 as sum;
+-----+
| sum |
+-----+
| 600 |
+-----+
```

---

Re your comment:

> Then why I can't use subquery results in aggregate functions? Something like: `select c.first_name, c.last_name from customer c where 20 = count(select customer_id from rental r where r.customer_id = c.customer_id));`

Well, you can't just make up syntax and expect it to work. No programming language works like that!

You can do this:

```
select c.first_name, c.last_name from customer c 
where 20 = (
  select count(*) from rental r 
  where r.customer_id = c.customer_id);
```

You can also do this:

```
select c.first_name, c.last_name from customer c
join rental r on r.customer_id = c.customer_id
group by c.customer_id
having count(*) = 20;
```

Comment: Then why I can't use subquery results in aggregate functions? Something like: `select c.first_name, c.last_name from customer c where 20 = count(select customer_id from rental r where r.customer_id = c.customer_id));`